# Swift: Custom UIAlertController view

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller, uiprogressview

The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uialertcontroller) say that subclassing UIAlertController is bad

> The UIAlertController class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.

So what is the recommended way to have an alert that shows not only a title, message and some buttons but also other stuff like ProgressBars, Lists, etc.?

In my special case I would like to have two different alerts, one that shows a ProgressBar and one that shows a list of error messages.

Currently I am trying to add the ProgressView manually and set constraints:

```
func getProgressAlert(onAbort: @escaping () -> ()) -> UIAlertController {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Test", message: "Test", preferredStyle: .alert)

    let abort = UIAlertAction (title: "Abort", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel) { _ in
        onAbort()
    }
    alert.addAction(abort)

    let margin:CGFloat = 8.0
    let rect = CGRect(x:margin, y:72.0, width: alert.view.frame.width - margin * 2.0 , height:2.0)
    self.progressView = UIProgressView(frame: rect)
    self.progressView!.setProgress(0.0, animated: false)
    self.progressView!.tintColor = UIColor.blue
    alert.view.addSubview(self.progressView!)
    self.progressView!.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.progressView!.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: alert.view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1.0).isActive = true
    self.progressView!.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 5.0).isActive = true
    self.progressView!.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: alert.view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    self.progressView!.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: alert.view.leftAnchor).isActive = true       

    return alert
}
```

I don't think this is the way this should be done as manually defining constraints is very prone to errors on different devices. For example, the current code just shows the progress bar on the top of the alert view, but I want it to be shown between the message and the abort button.

Comment: The recommended way is to write your own custom alert view and not use `UIAlertController`.

Comment: Yeah as rmaddy said, you just need to present a custom view controller.  Check out the UIViewController.modelPresentationStyle property, it'll help you overlay the custom view controller however you'd like it.  [ModalPresentationStyle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uimodalpresentationstyle)

Comment: Okay, so if I understand it correctly, UIAlertController is just a special implementation of an UIViewController that has some default elements, right? 
And now I should define my own class that inherits from UIViewController and then present that modally rather than using UIAlertController and modifying it.

Comment: Yes exactly.  Check out the "See Also" section of this [page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621355-modalpresentationstyle) to learn more about what you can do when presenting/dismissing custom view controllers.

Answer (score 9):

> The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.

This is pretty much the nail in the coffin for this API. If you try hack it, you will cause yourself a lot of pain trying to support it across different iOS versions.

If want to have custom controls on an alert you will have to write a custom `UIViewController` subclass and mimic the API as best as you can whilst adding your new functionality (if you do not want to do this, there will be examples available on GitHub).

Some examples:

- https://github.com/Codeido/PMAlertController
- https://github.com/Orderella/PopupDialog
- https://github.com/vikmeup/SCLAlertView-Swift
- https://github.com/sberrevoets/SDCAlertView

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did not use your examples but I found a really nice library: https://github.com/SwiftKickMobile/SwiftMessages
Works perfectly for me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The docs do indeed discourage subclassing UIAlertController. However it's easy to find examples of people circumventing this and sneaking subviews onto the alert's view, but they do so at their own peril of a minor iOS version update breaking it.

A big reason Apple places such limitations is because they reserve the right to change how this class works behind the scenes. UIAlertController does a lot of heavy lifting, and it used by many apps including those shipped by Apple.

But it only does what it does, and doesn't do what it doesn't. I don't think it's an accident that UIAlertController does not support the modal progress indication use case you describe. These types of UI "roadblocks" conflict with a good user experience.

Is there another way to achieve the same goals without using a modal? This might involve disabling other aspects of your UI until the work is done, but still allowing the user to navigate.  This would yield a better UX.

But if that's not going to work for you, and you must use a roadblocking modal progress indicator, acknowledging the negative UX it creates, it's more prudent and reliable to just build your own. UIAlertController is nothing special, it's a UIViewController like any other. It uses [publicly available API](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/PresentingaViewController.html) to control its frame size, how it overlays its presenting view, and how it animates on and off the screen. You'll save yourself a lot of headache by just rolling your own.